# Time rest issue after machine reboot

Tags: 12.04, time

I set a particular time in my VM machine which is containing Ubuntu 12.04 using some command. Time got changed soon after the command got executed, but if I reboot machine time is resetting back(which used to be before running command).

Comment: Which command did you use to set the time?

Answer (score 0):

Well - your issue isn't really that much descriptive, but anyway for proper time handling I'd recommend, first of all, two things:

1. proper time zone settings
2. using ntp to make sure local time doesn't go off - hardware clock (also the time presented by supervisor to guest systems with it) can drift over time.

Anyway - if that doesn't help yet with your issue, can you, please, present us examples of what was the time before and after - what and how much actually changed?

thanks